# Is it possible, that DisposeAsync method is called in parallel?

Tags: .net, thread-safety, dispose

Taking the following code from [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-disposeasync):

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ExampleAsyncDisposable : IAsyncDisposable, IDisposable
{
    private Utf8JsonWriter _jsonWriter = new Utf8JsonWriter(new MemoryStream());

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DisposeAsyncCore();

        Dispose(disposing: false);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _jsonWriter?.Dispose();
        }

        _jsonWriter = null;
    }

    protected virtual async ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore()
    {
        if (_jsonWriter is not null)
        {
            await _jsonWriter.DisposeAsync();
        }

        _jsonWriter = null;
    }
}
```

The question is: *Is the following scenario possible? And why?*

1. The `DisposeAsync` method is called.
2. Before the `_jsonWriter` is set to `null`, the `DisposeAsync` is called once again.

Comment: Async is kind of a red herring here. For even plain `Dispose`, it's an issue if there are multiple simultaneous callers, and it's a problem because you have multiple pieces of code that think that they "own" this disposable object and are responsible for cleanup. Don't let yourself get into that situation in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have concurrent `DisposeAsync` calls. It is also possible to have concurrent `Dispose` calls. Technically, implementations are *supposed* to handle this properly, but in real-world code, it's very rare to have concurrent `Dispose` or `DisposeAsync` calls, so most implementations do *not* handle this correctly.

If this is a source of concern, I recommend using my [Disposables](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Disposables) library, which ensures exactly-once semantics on disposal. However, it is written from the assumption that types want to implement `IAsyncDisposable` *or* `IDisposable`, and not both.